# Does iText 7 pdfHtml Support CSS Grid Layout?

Tags: c#, html, css, itext7, html-to-pdf

I can't seem to find a definitive answer on whether iText 7 supports CSS Grid layout. In my C# code, I'm simply using this line:

```
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(new FileInfo(@"testgrid.html"), new FileInfo(@"out.pdf"));
```

Note: I'm using iText 7 v7.1.12

Let's say my html/css code looks something like this:

```css
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 0;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div>
        <h3>A</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>B</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>C</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>D</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you run the html snippet above, you can see that the grid layout is displayed as expected, but when I run the C# code and open my `out.pdf` file, the grid styling is ignored and I see A, B, C, and D on separate lines.

[image]

Am I missing something, or does iText 7 `HtmlConverter` simply not support `display: grid;` in CSS?

Comment: I have also tried using IronPDF instead of iText 7 and even converted my code to use display: flex; instead of display: grid; but from what I can tell, it seems that both IronPDF and iText 7 don't support usage of display: grid; or display: flex;

Comment: It seems the recommended workaround is to use table instead. Is there not a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**IronPDF** and **iText 7** HTML to PDF converters both do not support `display: grid;` or `display: flex;`.

If you want to use C# to convert HTML/CSS to PDF but it contains grid/flex, I think the only way you can do it is by using headless chrome:

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
String command = "/C \"\"C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe\"\" --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=C:/users/xxxxx/Documents/file.pdf --print-to-pdf-no-header C:/users/xxxxx/Documents/file.html";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", command);
```

Comment: The latest versions of iText7 now support CSS Flexbox too.

Comment: IronPdf supports  display: grid; and display: flex; now in 2021